# Summing values in one field using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, summarizing, aggregate

In QGIS 2.18 there is a shapefile with three fields accordingly

| id | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 |
| 2 | b | NULL |
| 3 | c | 1 |
| 4 | d | 6 |
| 5 | e | NULL |

I want to get the total sum of all values in the field `"Value"`. How can I achieve that in the Python Console?

The field `"Value"` maintains two types of data `int` and `NULL`.

I was trying with a while-loop but it does not work

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

if not layer.isValid():
    raise Exception('Layer is not valid')

features = layer.getFeatures()

for feat in features:
    attr = feat.attributes()[2]
    
    if attr == NULL:
        continue

    else:
        total = 0
        index = 0
        while index < layer.featureCount():
            total = total + int(attr)
            index = index + 1
return(total)
```

How to achieve one number that gives the total sum of a whole field exclusive `NULL`-values?

> After executing @ahmadhanb's solution I received a correct number but
> somehow with a strange output type, when `print (type(sum(total)))` it gives me
> `<type 'NoneType'>`. What could be a problem?

---

**References:**

- [Find Neighbor Polygons in a Layer](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/find_neighbor_polygons.html)
- [Summing values from different intersecting/overlapping points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228756/summing-values-from-different-intersecting-overlapping-points-in-qgis)
- [Sum new values to existing attribute values in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252576/sum-new-values-to-existing-attribute-values-in-pyqgis)
- [SQL query in Python console to sum column based on values of other two columns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266670/qgis-sql-query-within-python-console-to-sum-a-column-based-on-values-of-other-t?rq=1)

Comment: Try to place the `print(total)` out of the loop. This will give you one value which is the total value.

Comment: @Taras you can replace `print(0)` with `continue` to skip null values.

Comment: Taras - What layer and field type is it and which QGIS version are you using? Would it be possible to share a sample of this data online so that others could test it? The one-liner from @Bera works for me in QGIS 2.18 and 3.4.

Comment: @Taras - Your sample dataset is missing a `.shx` file so it cannot be loaded.

Comment: @Taras - Your sample data works fine if I use `int(sum(filter(None,[f['Value'] for f in layer.getFeatures()])))` which returns the value `441`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In programming, there are several ways of solving a problem.

That's also the case for summing values of a field in QGIS. But there is one that is *the* recommended way, truly leveraging the PyQGIS API.

### Aggregating field values using PyQGIS

To get the sum of a field you can use:

```py
total_sum = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Sum, "my_field_name")
```

**Simpler and faster.**

Note: *Since the result is a tuple `(result_value, boolean_result)`, you just call `total_sum[0]` and you are done.*

---

[Read the docs](https://qgis.org/api/3.16/classQgsAggregateCalculator.html#a51eb9f5752cf107d72266829a21cf2fa) to know the list of aggregate types you can use.

You can even pass filter expressions to the aggregates. Really powerful.

---

*Note: this is available since QGIS 2.16.*

Comment: Thank you for such an explicit answer. I just checked and seems like the sum inside the tuple is a float type, is not it?

Comment: That's right @Taras.

Comment: @Taras, is that somehow relevant to you?

Comment: thank you, yes it is!

Comment: @Taras, which answer would you like new users to use? :)

Comment: The one with most reputation 

Comment: Disagree, since simpler is better, but I'll accept your choice.

Comment: I also disagree and at the same time agree with you. You are absolutely right that if there is an efficient/simple solution why not to use it. But as you can see I was(am) not that much advanced in PyQGIS, therefore we are talking about different sides of the "simplicity". Your approach is by any means better as it requires just one(max two) string(s) of code, mine is more naїve to understand where step by step you comprehend what exactly going on i.e. it is a mixture of first-steps in Python and basic things in PyQGIS. Also, at that time I simply did not know about `.aggregate()` method.

Comment: It's Ok @Taras. I see GIS.SE as a source of documentation and I think it should guide readers directly to the recommended response. But of course, you've got a point there.

Answer (score 5):

In fact your code provides a double number to the actual value. For example, if the total number is 50, your code provides 100. I think the correct code should be something like this:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

if not layer.isValid():
    raise Exception('Layer is not valid')

features = layer.getFeatures()

total = []
for feat in features:
    attr = feat.attributes()[2]

    if attr == NULL:
        continue

    else:
        total.append((int(attr)))
print(sum(total))
```

Add a total empty list outside the loop, and if the `attr == NULL`, it will skip the `null` values, and if there is a value in the `attr` it will be appended to the list. Then you can print the sum of the list outside the loop to get one value only.

Here is the screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: @Taras But I did not write print(type(sum(total))), I wrote print(sum(total)) which will provide an integer value. The output `print(type(sum(total)))` is `<class 'int'>` not <type 'NoneType'>

Comment: That is strange. Why do you get  `<type 'NoneType'>`? I am getting integer output type.

Comment: Shouldnt `if attr == NULL` be `if attr is None`?

Comment: @BERA Using `if attr is None` gives an error for integer field whereas `if attr == NULL` works well.

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS 3, [`QgsVectorLayerUtils.getValues()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayerUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayerUtils.getValues) returns all values from a specified field name or expression.

You can use to sum values in one field in that way:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
v = QgsVectorLayerUtils.getValues(layer, 'field_name')[0]
v = list(filter(None, v))
s = sum(v)
```

***NOTE***: `NULL is None` is `False` (both have different objects in the memory). `NULL == None` is `True` (both have the same value). Therefore, we can use `None` here.