# Finding mean and stdDev of vector layer field using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, statistics, qgis-python-console

I am going to standardized a vector layer field in Python console in QGIS, for that I want to get mean value and stdev value of the field.

How do I find mean and stdev in using PyQGIS.

I tried this. It is not working

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
idx=layer.fields().indexFromName("mean")
ave = layer.meanValue(idx)
print (ave)
stdDev = layer.stdDevValue(idx)
print (stdDev)
```

Comment: See my answer to [Summing values in one field using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397417/4972). In your case you'd need to use `QgsAggregateCalculator.mean` and `QgsAggregateCalculator.StDev` respectively. If that works for you, I'll close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. 
But I am getting this error
 **attributeError: type object 'QgsAggregateCalculator' has no attribute 'mean'**

Comment: Should be `QgsAggregateCalculator.Mean` (with a capital M).

Comment: Thank you so much I got it. This is working.

Comment: @Chathu_T, glad you got it working. FYI all Qgis api classes and methods are documented. It is a very good habit to adopt to consult the documentation e.g. https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAggregateCalculator.html#a51eb9f5752cf107d72266829a21cf2fa

Comment: Nice, @Chathu_T. Since [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397417/4972) works for you, don't forget to upvote it.