# Calculating information for selected parts of the polygon with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, features, area, qgis-python-console

I have a polygon that is formed using Quick OSM.

[image]

After that, I add an area calculation field to it, automatically using the QGIS tools.

[image]

How can I use PyQGIS to get the sum of the areas of the selected parts of the polygon multiplied by 5 and display the answer in the Python Console?

Comment: You could do all that using QGIS expressions, without Python. The solution must be using Python?

Comment: yes, it is on python

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify that you need a Python solution and add a code attempt. As it's currently written ("or in some other way") it suggests that you are open for other solutions as well. Maybe give a reason then why you need a Python version for a typical "non-Python" workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## To sum up all features' areas can be done either via

#### the `"FIELD_NAME"` field, that contains area values:

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsAggregateCalculator

# getting polygon layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]

# summing area of all features
area_total_sum = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Sum, "FIELD_NAME")

print(area_total_sum) # (19594.140492000002, True)
```

#### or the [`$area`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#area) variable directly:

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsAggregateCalculator

# getting polygon layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]

# summing area of all features
area_total_sum = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Sum, "$area")

print(area_total_sum) # (19594.140491519036, True)
```

Then if necessary proceed with `area_total_sum[0] * 5`.

If one applies this expression `area($geometry)` the result will be slightly different `(19603.3203125, True)`. Therefore, pay attention to this thread: [Calculating polygon areas in shapefile using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-shapefile-using-qgis).

## To sum up only selected features' areas can be done either via:

#### the [`aggregate()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#af55818cbac137eafffb541a4c8bc29c0) method of the `QgsVectorLayer` class:

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsAggregateCalculator

# getting polygon layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]

# summing area of selected features
area_selected_sum = layer.aggregate(
                            aggregate=QgsAggregateCalculator.Sum,
                            fieldOrExpression="FIELD_NAME",
                            fids=layer.selectedFeatureIds()
                            )

print(area_selected_sum) # (1958.09388, True)
```

#### or the [`calculate()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAggregateCalculator.html#ae953a382423ed79b5dc2e4d8f9feca92) method of the `QgsAggregateCalculator` class:

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsAggregateCalculator

# getting polygon layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]

# constructing the aggregate calculator
agg_calc = QgsAggregateCalculator(layer)
# setting a filter for selected features only
agg_calc.setFidsFilter(layer.selectedFeatureIds())

# summing area of selected features
area_selected_sum = agg_calc.calculate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Sum, "FIELD_NAME")

print(area_selected_sum) # (1958.09388, True)
```

As was already previously shown, instead of the `"FIELD_NAME"` one can also use either `$area` or `area($geometry)`.

Then if necessary proceed with `area_selected_sum[0] * 5`.

---

**References:**

- [Summing values in one field using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313901/summing-values-in-one-field-using-pyqgis)

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped me, and also a lot of different solutions, very cool

Answer (score 1):

here is the python script based on the data in the column Area from the attribute table

```
# Access the active layer (which should be your polygon layer)
layer = iface.activeLayer()
# Check if the layer is indeed a vector layer
if not layer or not isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
    print("Active layer is not a vector layer.")
else:
    # Initialize a variable to hold the sum of the areas
    sum_of_areas = 0
    
    # Loop through each selected feature in the layer
    for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
        # Assuming the field that stores the area is named 'Area'
        # Make sure to replace 'Area' with the actual name of your area field
        area = feature['Area']
        
        # Multiply the area by 5 and add to the total sum
        sum_of_areas += area * 5
    
    # Print the total sum in the Python Console
    print(f"The total sum of the selected areas multiplied by 5 is: {sum_of_areas}")
```